# ionic 2 blank google map

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2. I am try to practice [Integrating Native Google Maps into an Ionic 2 Application](http://www.joshmorony.com/integrating-native-google-maps-into-an-ionic-2-application/), but when I run app in android device, it give a blank google map as following image.

[image]

home.ts page is:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <div id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

home.scss is:

```
.scroll {
height: 100%;
}
#map {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
scroll-content._gmaps_cdv_{
background-color: transparent !important;
padding: 0px !important;
}
ion-app._gmaps_cdv_ .nav-decor{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
home-page {
}
```

home.ts is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { GoogleMap, GoogleMapsEvent, GoogleMapsLatLng } from 'ionic-native';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  map: GoogleMap;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });
  }
  loadMap(){
    let location = new GoogleMapsLatLng(-34.9290,138.6010);
    this.map = new GoogleMap('map', {
      'backgroundColor': 'white',
      'controls': {
        'compass': true,
        'myLocationButton': true,
        'indoorPicker': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'gestures': {
        'scroll': true,
        'tilt': true,
        'rotate': true,
        'zoom': true
      },
      'camera': {
        'latLng': location,
        'tilt': 30,
        'zoom': 15,
        'bearing': 50
      }
    });
    this.map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).subscribe(() => {
      console.log('Map is ready!');
    });
  }
}
```

I did not change any other page.

My google developer console API manager is:

[image]

I do not know what I miss.

Comment: It means that you have not enabled api from console. make sure that you have enabled console as well as Location from device

Comment: Please do not show your api keys public. Since you are getting all your map controls, GoogleMaps is working successfully to you. Add a class to your ion-content, and then in your scss make the class background and color transparent. It works for me.

Comment: I add the class but not work for me.Should I change the index.html or not.

Comment: Remove your api keys asap!

Comment: Thanks from your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing my iOS and android key restriction.

Comment: Can you tell me how do you do this please? I am having exact same issue and cannot fix it...